# Stops BottomNavigationView from increasing items font size on click

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, font-size, bottomnavigationview

The default behavior of BottomNavigationView makes the items fonts size increase when clicking on them, causing some longer titles to get truncated.

I'd like to avoid the font size increase, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your text size in dimensions file with the following key

```
 <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
```

For remove blinking, you have to disable shifting.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView;
import android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShifting(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("Error BottomBar", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("Error BottomBar", e.getLocalizedMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

Apply this class to your navigation view

```
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

Comment: It works but unfortunately there is a slight blink when clicking on the item. Is it possible to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Now you don't need to use reflection for disable shifting.

From support library `28.0.0` or material library, new method was added.

`setLabelVisibilityMode()` check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.html#setLabelVisibilityMode(int)).

you can use it like.

```
bottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED);
```